# Can no longer upvote comments on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I use the Android Stack Exchange app for most of my SE activity nowadays.  Just now I've noticed that I can no longer upvote comments: after tap-selecting one, I get a profile icon button, a "COPY TEXT" button, and a three-dots menu that only contains "Share".

I'm not sure when exactly I last upvoted a comment, but it was likely within the last week, and possibly the last few hours.

I'm using version 1.0.89, which hasn't been updated since September of last year.  Was there a server-side update that changed this?  Or perhaps something has changed locally on my device (I'm definitely still logged in)?

Comment: Pretty sure I just upvoted a comment on my Android. Are you vote-banned for some reason?

Comment: @Carcigenicate there is no such thing as vote ban.

Answer (score 1):

Most-likely you were just on a site you have not joined yet.

If you have not joined a site yet, those are the 3 buttons you see.

If you are on a site you have joined, the upvote button will be there, and the profile button will be under the 3 dots menu.

### Not joined vs joined:

[image: not-joined screenshot] [image: joined screenshot]

Comment: It is a site I have joined (and have thousands of rep on). I can vote, leave comments, answer, etc. as normal.

Comment: Actually, no: voting tells me I haven't joined, and prompts me to (which does nothing). So there's some sort of joined/not-joined bug going on.

Comment: @Xiong Which site? Does it happen for all comments in that site, or just some?

Answer (score 1):

The app seemed to believe I wasn't logged in, in some contexts, on only one site. I don't know why.

I logged out and back in and that fixed it.

Comment: That's not a proper fix. The app should prompt you to join the site (similar to when you attempt to upvote a Q or A). Then upon joining (which is what i did), you should be able to upvote comments.  I had same problem and almost submitted separate bug report, but found this post.